# Shop-Script, webasyst: какой контроллер получает данные из БД, когда мы кладем товар в корзину?

Tags: php, cms, controller

Добрый день, уважаемое сообщество!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой именно контроллер получает данные из базы, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" для товара в CMS Shop-Script, Webasyst?

(к сожалению, документация довольно скудна на данный момент!)

Такой вопрос возник при выполнении следующей задачи: необходимо было корректировать $product['price'] (цену товара) в зависимости от передаваемого параметра (статуса пользователя: 1- обычный, 2-оптовый. Для пользователей с разным статусом должны выводится цены соответствующих артикулов вместо основной цены). Для карточки товара все решилось добавкой условия в wa-apps\shop\lib\classes\shopProduct.class, для коллекции товаров в категории магазина условие было добавлено в shopProductsCollection.class. При этом, если добавить товар в корзину, то он добавляется со стандартной ценой, хранящейся в столбце price таблице shop_product. А нужно, чтобы система искала артикул с флагом статуса пользователя и брала цену из соответствующей записи из таблицы shop_product_skus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ShopScript6 за добавление в корзину отвечает shopFrontendCartAddController, но логичнее и правильнее сделать свою обработку события или отправлять сабмит формы на отдельный url, который потом перехватывать собственным плагином (указав соответствующие настройки в lib/config/routing.php).